# How can I execute a Windows command line in background?

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I execute a windows command line in the background, without it interacting with the active user?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do? Do you want to perform a command on the command line in background or do you want to perform the whole command line in background, so it is unvisible from the desktop?

Comment: i need two cane perform a command on the command line in background or do you want to perform the whole command line in background

Comment: Duplicates [this question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/121979/tools-to-run-a-background-process-command-line-in-windows/714560).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but there is a [post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window) which may contain the information you need. The answer there describes how to run a batch file window hidden:

> You could run it silently using a Windows Script file instead. The Run
>   Method allows you running a script in invisible mode. Create a `.vbs`
>   file like this one
>
> ```vbs
> Dim WinScriptHost
> Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Scheduled Jobs\mybat.bat" & Chr(34), 0
> Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
> ```
>
> and schedule it. The second argument in this example sets the window
>   style. 0 means "hide the window."

Comment: This is perfect. SetPoint for Logitech never, NEVER, starts with windows. I've been starting it manually for about 3 years now. Does it matter where the batch is? I've seen some people put this type of batch file in C, or the root.

Comment: It really isn't vague if you are used to linux. Just put a & at the end and its backgrounded.

Answer (score 375):

This is a little late but I just ran across this question while searching for the answer myself and I found this:

```
START /B program
```

which, on Windows, is the closest to the Linux command:

```
program &
```

From the console HELP system:

```
C:\>HELP START

Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
      [command/program] [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in window title bar.
    path        Starting directory.
    B           Start application without creating a new window. The
                application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
                enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
                the application.
```

One problem I saw with it is that  you have more than one program writing to the console window, it gets a little confusing and jumbled.

To make it not interact with the user, you can redirect the output to a file:

```
START /B program > somefile.txt
```

Comment: I like this answer best because it doesn't open another command window

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, it seems to only create a new cmd instance [?] however if I run it like `start /B "" program` then it worked...

Comment: @rogerdpack That's right. For some reason with Windows 7, this is the command format. The "" is the mandatory title parameter.

Comment: @ejbytes I run Windows 7 and I don't need the empty parameter `""` in order for it to work.

Comment: @Novicaine: How do I abort a process I have started that way? Ctrl+c doesn't have any effect on in.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I exit the shell window in which I spawned the process, it looks like the process also terminates.

Comment: How do you enable `^C` processing for such application?

Comment: @Qwerty: Look at the MSDN for SetConsoleCtrlHandler

Comment: This is cool, but is there a way to specify WHICH `start` to run? I have unfortunately a `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\start` that wants to run instead (I found it with `where start`. It seems `START` here is a built-in command, but windows only wants to run the MinGW one.

Comment: @Novicaine: either open Task Manager (`ctrl`+`shift`+`esc`) and find the process on the list, or use `taskkill.exe /im nameofprocess.exe /f`. I believe you also have the choice of specifying a PID with `taskkill.exe` but I'm not sure

Comment: @palswim, I don't know what Windows edition you refer to, but in Windows 10 I tried `start /B %WinDir%\System32\Taskmgr.exe`, and closing the command-line window did not close Task Manager.

Answer (score 96):

I suspect you mean: Run something in the background and get the command line back immediately with the launched program continuing.

```
START "" program
```

Which is the Unix equivalent of

```
program &
```

Comment: what is the fg equivalent? Can we close the command prompt and the porgram will still run?

Comment: Also, I want to run a program in command prompt and return to it from time to time, like in screen - is that doable with this? I need to be able to close the command prompt but keep the running program usable.

Comment: What's that empty parameter of `start`? It doesn't work without it (executes just a new command instance), but `start`'s help doesn't say anything about it, it states all parameters are optinional (or I don't understand it).

Comment: @DawidFerenczy `start` works without the empty parameter for me, but I seem to get a shells with a separate configuration when I use the empty parameter, as a setting I did when I didn't have the empty parameter isn't used when I do use the empty parameter. I wonder why they use separate configurations?

Comment: @Paul `START "" program` starts a command in a new terminal for me, while `program &` in Unix runs the command in and prints the output to the same terminal.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Sorry, but I don't understand a single sentence. "the empty parameter isn't used when I do use the empty parameter" doesn't make a sense at all.

Comment: @Dawid, I can see that my sentence was a bit ambiguous. "Isn't used" didn't refer to the empty parameter, but to the setting that I did (changed?) when I didn't use the empty parameter. In both cases (with/without the `""` parameter), I get a new cmd window. The first time, when I called `START` without the `""` parameter, I changed a setting to the cmd. Later when I called `START` _with_ the `""` parameter, the setting had been undone.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye It worked for me with a GUI program, closed the command prompt immediately after starting it. I assume you're trying to start a command-line program in the background.

Answer (score 19):

```
START /MIN program
```

the above one is pretty closer with its Unix counterpart `program &`

Answer (score 12):

You can use this (commented!) PowerShell script:

```ps
# Create the .NET objects
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$newproc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
# Basic stuff, process name and arguments
$psi.FileName = $args[0]
$psi.Arguments = $args[1]
# Hide any window it might try to create
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true
$psi.WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
# Set up and start the process
$newproc.StartInfo = $psi
$newproc.Start()
# Return the process object to the caller
$newproc
```

Save it as a `.ps1` file. After enabling script execution (see Enabling Scripts in [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info)), you can pass it one or two strings: the name of the executable and optionally the arguments line. For example:

```
.\hideproc.ps1 'sc' 'stop SomeService'
```

I confirm that this works on Windows 10.

Comment: yep start /b no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

This is how my PHP internal server goes into background. So technically it should work for all.

```
start /B "" php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A related answer, with 2 examples:

1. Below opens calc.exe:

> call START /B "my calc" "calc.exe"

2. Sometimes foreground is not desireable, then you run minimized as below:

> call start /min "n" "notepad.exe"
>
> call START /MIN "my mongod" "%ProgramFiles%\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to run it minimized: `call Start /MIN  "c" "calc.exe"`

Comment: correct, it works for notepad:    call start /min "n" "notepad.exe"

Comment: So it works for windowed applications but not for console applications. Figures, as one can pass the `SW_*` to [`CreateProcessW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) via `STARTUPINFO::wShowWindow` (including `SW_HIDE`).

Comment: What is a full command, with above like "start" or other tool? do we need to write another program?

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, you just need to pass Process Creation Flag of `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, as simple as that.

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy You can use [my utility](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/ql) as and example, or as is!

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer your point being? I was referring to how this answer does not work for console applications and how the flags to `start` likely map to the underlying API. If you can tell how to achieve the same with `start`, sure I'll give that a shot. While being a developer, when using NT script I am merely a user of existing facilities.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the command-line program to run without the user even knowing about it, define it as a Windows Service and it will run on a schedule.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: Alternatively you can make it a scheduled task - Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Scheduled Tasks or use the `schtasks` command in Windows XP and above (warning: `schtasks` is complicated).

Answer (score 0):

just came across this thread
windows 7 , using power shell, runs executable's in the background , exact same as unix  filename &

example:  start -NoNewWindow  filename

help start

NAME
    Start-Process

SYNTAX
    Start-Process [-FilePath]  [[-ArgumentList] ] [-Credential ] [-WorkingDirectory
    ] [-LoadUserProfile] [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError ] [-RedirectStandardInput
    ] [-RedirectStandardOutput ] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle  {Normal | Hidden |
    Minimized | Maximized}] [-UseNewEnvironment]  []

```
Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [-PassThru] [-Verb
<string>] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle <ProcessWindowStyle> {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}]
[<CommonParameters>]
```

ALIASES
    saps
    start

Comment: I don't have Windows 7 anymore to test this on [Windows 11 here] -- but start.exe is also a command. To make this work, without aliases since 'start' is a different but similar command, call it directly from within PowerShell: Start-Process -NoNewWindow filename

Answer (score 0):

You can see the correct way to do this in this link:

[How to Run a Scheduled Task Without a Command Window Appearing](http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-without-a-command-window-appearing/)

Summarizing, you have to checkbox for 'Run whether user is logged on or not'. Task user credentials should be enter after pressing 'Ok'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [my utility](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/ql). I think the source code should be self explanatory. Basically `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag.

Answer (score -1):

I did this in a batch file:
by starting the apps and sending them to the background. Not exact to the spec, but it worked and I could see them start.

```
rem   Work Start Batch Job from Desktop
rem   Launchs All Work Apps
@echo off
start "Start OneDrive" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"
start  "Start Google Sync" "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\GoogleDriveSync.exe"
start skype
start "Start Teams" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe"
start Slack
start Zoom
sleep 10
taskkill /IM "explorer.exe"
taskkill /IM "teams.exe"
taskkill /IM "skype.exe"
taskkill /IM "slack.exe"
taskkill /IM "zoom.exe"
taskkill /IM "cmd.exe"
@echo on
```

killing explorer kills all explorer windows, I run this batch file after start up, so killing explorer is no issue for me.
You can seemingly have multiple explorer processes and kill them individually but I could not get it to work.
killing cmd.exe is to close the CMD window which starts because of the bad apps erroring.

Comment: You are launching work apps and then terminating them all ? Why ?

Comment: Amit, many of the comments in previous questions asked about how to interact/close running programs you open. This is apparently an illustration of how to do that.