# How do I launch a program in the background

Tags: command-line, windows-10

Due to many problems on my system, when I launch a program, it crashes whenever I <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> out of it. I need to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> out in order to launch another necessary program. To try and avert this problem, I created a script to launch the program, and then launch the other program without me having to exit the program.

I thought this would work, but instead of doing what I wanted, it launched both programs, but when the second program launched, it would automatically come into focus, crashing my other program. Basically, I need to know how to launch a program from a batch script in the background, that is to say, without it automatically coming into focus.

Comment: What are the two programs??

Comment: I am trying to launch a game and a VoIP Client. I can't exit the game without it crashing.

Comment: What happens if you first launch the VoIP client and then the game?

Comment: Also, which game is it? Some games have a borderless windowed mode, which looks full-screen but really isnt. Usually the crash is due to the screen resolution changing, and this prevents it.

Comment: It is Medal of Honor: Allied Assault.

Comment: Ah, I remember that game., It does not have windowed borderless fullscreen mode, and alt-tab is not possible and crashes the game while full screen. Pressing Alt-Enter to go to windowed mode should work though. Once in windowed mode, you should be able to alt-tab out.

Comment: Anything interesting in [this thread](http://superuser.com/q/198525/257269)? Ps> Welcome on SuperUser. Take some moment to read [ask]. Try to search if someone else did the same question before...

Answer (score 0):

To launch a program in the background add **&** to the end of the line.

example

```
watch lessc input.less output.css &;
```

Comment: As you can see the tag is Windows-10, i think your answer is more approbate for a Unix based OS than windows