# Command prompt : Move running process to background

Tags: cmd.exe, signal

In most Linux shells, you can "stop" a running process foreground with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and use `bg` to move it into the background.

What's the Command Prompt equivalent? This should be a duplicate but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It's not possible. The nearest equivalent is [How can I execute a Windows command line in background?](http://superuser.com/q/198525)

Answer (score 3):

Start your process like this:

> Start /B someCommand -v

Then to bring it back enter:

> exit

Which exits the foreground cmd.exe and brings back the background process.