# How do you write a script in windows that starts without a window?

Tags: windows, putty

I run pageant (part of putty) at windows startup.  There is currently (as of version .69 and .70) a bug where it dies after some time.

Therefore I want to write a script (bat, powershell, I don't mind which), in windows that essentially does this:

```
:loop
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" C:\Users\user\Documents\mykey.ppk
goto loop
```

How do I do this such that there isn't a cmd window lying around?

This is perhaps related to [How can I execute a Windows command line in background?](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background)  But I don't want to start pageant in the background of the bat file otherwise it loops quickly.

I want the script itself to execute in the background and not to have a window.  I prefer to do this in a single script.  As in, not have to create a shortcut that starts a script.

Answer (score 0):

Use a command line tool to silently launch a process

Quiet, hidecon or hideexec

`/NOCONSOLE` after you cmd.exe

You go one thing if you need it in Minimized process without changing the Code.

Go to CMD --> Open CMD --> Right Click on the taskbar of CMD Icon. You Can see Command Prompt --> again right Click on that --> Properties --> You Can RUN: You get three Option Min, Max and Normal windows. Select MIN. --> APPLY --> OK

So whenever you run CMD it would open with MINIMIZED windows.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem like an answer at all to my question.