# Batch file with multiple commands

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I have a batch file to start several programs. it has quit working. It starts the 1st 2 and stops. No error message.

e.g.

```
G:\KarenPwrTool\Replicator\PTReplicator.exe
G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe F:\alk
G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe G:
```

I'm using Windows 10 version 22h2.

Comment: Please show us the file. Please also run the bat file in a cmd window so that you can capture the output. Also, check Event Viewer for any errors that appear relevant.

Comment: i included the 1st 3 lines in the post. the cmd window just shows the 1st 2 lines which executed fine, then nothing.

Comment: That is not clear, and it is not all of the information requested. There are formatting tools you can use in the Editor window to make it clear you are presenting the code. Please also do the other things requested and provide that information.

Comment: "G:\KarenPwrTool\Replicator\PTReplicator.exe"
G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe F:\alk

G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe G: 
i looked in event viewer and don't see anything relevant.

Comment: There is an EDIT button below your post that you should use. Making your question more clear and complete is in your best interest. Not adding comments: making the question more clear.

Comment: this is the 1st 3 lines in the .bat file."G:\KarenPwrTool\Replicator\PTReplicator.exe"
G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe F:\alk

G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe G: 
i don't know how to use mini-markdown to make it clearer.

Comment: There is a Help section, and there were guides when you first wrote your question here. Please read those guides and visit the Help section to better understand how this site works. There is an EDIT button below the main question. This is the last time I will be helping you.

Comment: i don't see an edit button by my initial question. where can i find instructions for mini-markdown? how can i maintain formatting in the comment box? at this point i am baffled as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat an educated guess, but it seems to me that you want to start the (in this example) three programs in a row without stopping/hanging/waiting for each to complete, just like the Linux command suffix `&` in `startProgram &`.

To achieve this, you could use the approach of [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/591084/427002). It simply states that you can use the `start /B` prefix before your commands.

So, after applying this fix, your batch file could look like this:

```
start /B G:\KarenPwrTool\Replicator\PTReplicator.exe
start /B G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe F:\alk
start /B G:\FileManagers\VfileViewer\v.exe G:
```

If you need the output, use the redirect solution from the end of the answer.

Comment: thank you, this works for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer solves your question please accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left side of the question.